# DQL Syntaxe error with JOIN

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I have this error :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 142: Error: Expected end of string, got 'v'

With this code :

```
SELECT p, b, v
FROM CmsCmsBundle:Page p
JOIN p.blocks b
JOIN b.content v
WHERE p.id = :id
ORDER BY
b.position ASC
v.position ASC
```

This version without the "v" works:

```
SELECT p, b
FROM CmsCmsBundle:Page p
JOIN p.blocks b
WHERE p.id = :id
ORDER BY
b.position ASC
```

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a comma after the first `ASC`: `ORDER BY
b.position ASC, 
v.position ASC`

Comment: That's it! Stupid error thanks Chessemacfly